# User registration in Scotty

Tags: haskell, authentication, registration, scotty

While learning Haskell I've made a small web app in [Scotty](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty) framework. Next I'd like to add user registration.

Registration should support email/password and Google/FaceBook login options. If user registers "on site" he should also be able to login with G/FB account and vice versa.

Is there some standard/easy way of achieving this with [Scotty](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty)?

I don't really like doing registration and authentication my self, but I guess just some pointers on how to implement standard email/password reg/auth would be helpful.